# How to filter out data by Dates before using a Group BY clause SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a data that looks similar like below:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (
PERSONID int,
Diagnosis varchar(255),
AdmissionDate date
)

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE
VALUES
('1','Broken Bone','2019-12-01'),
('2','Headache','2019-12-02'),
('3','Cancer','2020-01-05'),
('4','Broken Bone','2020-02-01'),
('5','Broken Bone','2020-03-01'),
('6','Headache','2020-03-06'),
('7','Cancer','2020-04-05')
```

I am trying to use a group by clause like below:

```
SELECT
Diagnosis,
COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDiagnosis
FROM EXAMPLE
GROUP BY Diagnosis
```

However, I would like to only select the group by clause on data that has an admission date before 2020-03-1. I have an understanding that I should use a subquery or nested queries but I am not sure how to execute that. My Desired Output is something like the table below:

| Diagnosis | NumberOfDiagnosis |
| --- | --- |
| Broken Bone | 2 |
| Headache | 1 |
| cancer | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `where clause`

```
SELECT
Diagnosis,
COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDiagnosis
FROM EXAMPLE
where AdmissionDate<'2020-03-01'
GROUP BY Diagnosis
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a `where` clause:

```
SELECT Diagnosis, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDiagnosis
FROM EXAMPLE
WHERE AdmissionDate < '2020-03-01'
GROUP BY Diagnosis;
```

This filters the data *before* aggregation so only records before that date are included in the result set.